# Angle Chase from SEAMO 2021

Tags: geometry

[image: figure 1]

Let $D$ be a point inside triangle $ABC$ such that:

- $\overline{AB}=\overline{CD}$
- $∠DAC=35°$
- $∠DCA=15°$
- $∠ABC=50°$

Evaluate $∠DAB$ in degrees.

I have tried using standard angle chasing but to no avail.
I confuse as how to use $\overline{AB}=\overline{CD}$ in this case.

Comment: Angle in "B" equals 50°, the one in "D" equals 130°, the sum of both is 180°, can't you use that for saying that mirroring "D" over "AC" gives you a figure of four points, lying on a circle?

Comment: Ive tried that before, let me try again.

Comment: It seems reflecting $D$ directly over $AC$ may not be of much help, since we do not get to use $AB=CD$. Then one idea can be to complete $\parallel^{\text{gm}} ADCE$, again $E$ is on circumcircle of $ABC$ and use isosceles $\triangle ABE$ thus formed.

Comment: Let $AD$ meet the circle again at $F$. Show $CDF$ isosceles. $CD=CF=AB$

Answer (score 3):

Reflect $D$ across $AC$ to $D'$. Since $\angle ADC = 130^\circ$, the quadrilateral $ABCD'$ is cyclic.

Since $AB = CD = CD',$ the minimal arcs $AB$ and $CD'$ are congruent,
therefore (by inscribed angles),
$\angle ACB = \angle CAD' = 35^\circ$
and $AD'$ is parallel to $BC$.

We then find that $\angle BAD' = 130^\circ$,  and the angle chasing is easy from that point on.

Comment: Oh direct reflection works, producing very simple solution. $\angle BAD = \angle BAD' - 2\angle DAC = 60^\circ$. +1

Answer (score 1):

Let $AC=1$.  From triangle $ADC$ we get

$$\frac{DC}{\sin(35)}=\frac{1}{\sin(130)},$$
hence
$$AB=DC=\frac{\sin(35)}{\sin(130)}.$$

Invoking the Law of Sine in triangle $ABC$ we find
$$
\frac{\sin\bigl(\angle(BCA)\bigr)}{AB}=\frac{\sin(50)}{1}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Another approach: Draw a line parallel with BC , it meets extension of AC at E.Draw circumcircle of triangle ABE. Extend BD to meet the circle at G. We have:

$\angle GBE=35+15=50^o\Rightarrow \overset{\large\frown }{EG}=100^o$

$\angle BAE=50^o\Rightarrow \overset{\large\frown }{BE}=100^o$

So E is mid point of arc BEG. Perpendicular from E on BG is diameter of circle and meets it at H, so we have:

$\overset{\large \frown}{GH}=\overset{\large \frown}{BH}=80\Rightarrow \angle HBG=40^o$

Similarly we can show that A is midpoint of arc BH and  arc AH is $40^o$ which results in:

$\angle ABH=20^o\Rightarrow \angle ABD=40 +20=60^o$